# Find the exit to the labyrinth

Tags: prolog

I have to find the exit path to this labyrinth.

[image: 1]

The labyrinth must be represented with connect events eg connect(1,7), connect(2,8) etc.
The output path must be a list with start on the left edge and finish on the right edge.
I have written the following code:

```
connect(start,2).
connect(1, 7).
connect(7, 13).
connect(13, 14).
connect(14,15).
connect(15,21).
connect(14,20).
connect(20,26).
connect(26,27).
connect(27,28).
connect(28,29).
connect(23,29).
connect(17,23).
connect(11,17).
connect(5,11).
connect(5,6).
connect(19,25).
connect(25,31).
connect(31,32).
connect(32,33).
connect(33,34).
connect(34,35).
connect(35,36).
connect(12, 18).
connect(18, 24).
connect(24,30).
connect(30,36).
connect(2, 8).
connect(2,3).
connect(3,4).
connect(8,9).
connect(3, 9).
connect(4,10).
connect(10,16).
connect(16, 22).
connect(21, 22).
connect(32,finish).
```

I have stuck to the commands needed for finding the path.

Comment: I think you need to add the fact `connect(28, 34)`.

Comment: Seen here a couple of days ago, with answer but no engagement from whomever posted that one about whether it worked or helped https://old.reddit.com/r/prolog/comments/sa2onc/prolog_labyrinth/

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler we can make small breaking changes in the code we post (with full notice about that of course), to avoid such unpleasantness.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from a smaller one.

[image]

We represent it as

```
connect(2,8).
connect(3,2).
connect(3,exit).
connect(3,9).
connect(8,9).

cango(A,B) :- connect(A,B).
cango(A,B) :- connect(B,A).
```

And program it as simply as possible,

```
path(    Start,      [Start | Path]) :- 
         Start = exit,        Path = [].
path(    Start,      [Start | Path]) :- 
  cango( Start, Next), 
  path(         Next,         Path).
```

and that's it. And it even works,

```
3 ?- path(2,P).
P = [2, 3, exit] ;
P = [2, 3, exit, 3, exit] ;
P = [2, 3, exit, 3, exit, 3, exit] ;
P = [2, 3, exit, 3, exit, 3, exit, 3, exit] .
```

Wait, no, it doesn't. It gets stuck, with the above facts as shown, and doesn't even produce the first possible path, let alone avoiding this unwelcome repetitiveness.

But it did, when I tried it with a different set of `connect` facts -- and then I made a change, but a very small one, that broke this program. Yet the above set of `connect` facts does *correctly describe* the labyrinth...

All you need to do to make it work again is swap the arguments to *one* `connect` fact above. Try it. Does it produce any results now? Does it produce the *same* `Path` result as the one shown above, when we call it as `path(2,Path)`?

Then try swapping the order of the `connect` facts to get the same `Path` as shown above.

Then change the program so that it is impervious to such small differences in representation, and works for any set of facts that *correctly* *describe* the situation, not just such that was made specifically so the above simple program doesn't get stuck.

Then / or, change it so it produces all possible paths in order of their length.

Then change it so it produces the shortest path.

There, a whole learning program / *path* ahead of you.